# How to compress EJS output in expressJS framework?

Tags: html, node.js, express, templates, ejs

I am new to `NodeJS, Express` and **templates**

I am trying to generate a table and send the output to user and it is working
fine using `EJS` but the html generated has lots of whitespace.

So when a size of generated html file is around `148kb` after using online html compressor then size becomes **38kb**

So how do i compress html after rendering and send it to user.

is there a build-in method in express or ejs

**I know that pug already generates compressed html but i want to use `EJS`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no built in method, try [express-minify-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-minify-html)

```
const express = require('express');

const minifyHTML = require('express-minify-html');

const app = express();

app.use(minifyHTML({
    override: true,
    exception_url: false,
    htmlMinifier: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        minifyJS: true
    }
}));
```